Can't access Desktop, Documents, etc. from remote machine on same network using SMB since upgrade
I have two Mac machines running macOS 14.5 (Sonoma) on the same LAN. With a previous machine which was running an earlier version of macOS (forgotten which one), the following worked:
In Finder, from Network, select name of remote machine (visible as File Sharing is on for remote machine), and enter credentials (userid and password used for local login on the remote machine). Then in Finder, the file structure of the remote machine was visible (or at least the parts that that user could see).
With the new machine, all works the same, except that Desktop, Documents, etc. show zero items when navigating to them. I guess this has something to do with TCC (Transparency, Consent, and Control). When using the machine locally, I get prompted when a new application tries to access these folders and have to manually give permission. I'm guessing that whatever 'application' on the remote machine is trying to access these in order to serve them up using SMB on the other machine does not have permission, but that there is no possibility to create the pop-up window to ask for permission. Or possibly it is something else completely, but hours of web research has not found me a solution.
Any ideas?
